# When are contiguous C++ arrays really faster than Java/C# ArrayLists?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, stl

So I kinda stole the question title from [this isocpp entry over here](http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/04/contiguous-arrays).

#### *When* is a contiguous collection/container faster than a non-contiguous one?

- What about *inserting*?
- Accessing elements - Does it matter whether the elements are a POD (e.g. `double`) or a complex object (e.g. `std::string`)
- Copying the array (and it's contents, depending on language)?

There are tradeoffs to be made when using (C++) data structures. While `std::vector` is fine, and the [thing about memory layout](http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/04/contiguous-arrays) certainly true, I think people really also need to understand in which scenarios it's not so great.

<sub>Note: I do have a pretty clear idea myself, but provided this isn't closed I'd like to see what others think before I provide a possible answer myself.</sub>

Comment: I can't make any sense of this question. When is a contiguous array faster than a non-contiguous one? Counter-question: why do you call a set of non-contiguous memory segments an "array"?

Comment: @Jon - you are right. I rephrased and removed the "arrray"

Comment: @hvd - Read the link. The ArrayList is just a contiguous array of pointers, and the data will be non-contiguous.

Comment: *"Does it matter whether the elements are a POD or a complex object"* I think this is the wrong discrimination. Contiguous data structures are claimed to be fast because of simple memory access patterns (contiguous access). Some `struct node { int* element; };` is a POD but can hurt performance if `*element` is required from some `vector<node>`. Similarly, `std::string` typically uses a small string optimization, where no indirections are necessary.

Comment: @MartinBa It was not clear to me from the question that that was what you meant. In hindsight, it probably should have been obvious.

Comment: It is never faster.  These VMs have smart garbage collectors, they keep the data contiguous even if they have to use pointers.  Much unlike C++ code, once a shared_ptr<> pointer is allocated then you're stuck with where the object is located.  The only possible gain you get from native code is being able to bypass the array index check.  No slamdunk, it is often optimized away if the jitter can see that the index is never out of range.  Herb Sutter's [session at Build](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661) reminds us again of how important this is, skip to about 25:00

Comment: @Hans - your comment seems to contradict what Herb shows on the slides. "smart garbage collectors, they keep the data contiguous even if they have to use pointers" ... really??

Comment: Yes, really.  Herb skipped that minor detail, it is not popular news in a room filled with C++ programmers :)  Very simple to implement of course.

Comment: @HansPassant then what is the point of `struct` in C#? And why do you assume the room was full of C++ programmers, at a language-agnostic conference about developing for MS platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) chose a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961801/when-are-contiguous-c-arrays-really-faster-than-java-c-arraylists?noredirect=1#comment35062490_22961801), but I really think this deserves an answer:

> It is never faster. These VMs have smart garbage collectors, they
>   keep the data contiguous even if they have to use pointers. Much
>   unlike C++ code, once a shared_ptr<> pointer is allocated then you're
>   stuck with where the object is located. The only possible gain you get
>   from native code is being able to bypass the array index check. No
>   slamdunk, it is often optimized away if the jitter can see that the
>   index is never out of range. Herb Sutter's session at Build reminds us
>   again of how important this is, skip to about 25:00 –  Hans Passant 20
>   mins ago

... seems to contradict [what Herb shows on the slides](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661) (ca 26:00 - 28:00). "smart garbage collectors, they keep the data contiguous even if they have to use pointers" ... really??

> Yes, really. Herb skipped that minor detail, it is not popular news
>   in a room filled with C++ programmers :) Very simple to implement of
>   course. –  Hans Passant 4 mins ago

Note: *I* do not if "it is never faster", but it still is a useful and thought provoking answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch the complete video, there is kind of a benchmark in the middle where it shows that for some scenario, the cost of cache misses with contiguous-but-not-really array (array of pointers like in C#/Java) can be enormous, compared to the real contiguous std::vector storing the actual elements and not pointers (using standard C++ value semantic).